# Arial always show up as bold in my system

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word, windows-8.1, fonts

Lately (I'm not sure exactly when, but sometime during the last couple of weeks) pages in my browser has looked strange, and that is because the default font (Arial) looks bold all the time.

Here is a screenshot from the font settings in Chrome [image]

As you can see the Arial font looks bold here, and it does not on my other computer.

I have tried to copy the Arial fonts from my machine where it looks normal to the machine where it looks wrong, but it still displays the same on that machine.

It's not just a Chrome problem since it happens in all browsers, in Word and so on.

I'm running Windows 8.1.

This is **extremly** annoying, so I hope someone has some idea of what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to reinstall the Arial TrueType font on your system (`Arial.ttf`). Either do a search for it in your Windows directory or download it from a trusted source and then install it (this is done by simply double clicking the `.ttf` file.

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/261038/firefox-4-is-displaying-all-text-as-bold) for a lengthier version. Including a download link. Please note, I haven't tested nor validated the link in the question I linked above, so please scan with your antivirus software before using the contents.

Comment: That was already tried from the computer where the fonts looks normal. I tried with all the 9 Arial variants I have on my system (arial*.ttf)

Comment: please confirm that you didnt only copy the fonts to the PC that experiences the problem but also installed them by either double clicking on the `.ttf` file or via right click -> install font. I just want to make sure it's not a simple fix.

Comment: Yep, I closed all applications, double clicked each ttf file and selected install font, then restarted my system.

Comment: Please try and see if this works: Type `chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write` (or copy-paste) in your address bar, select "enable" under "disable directwrite", and then "restart chrome" at bottom.

Comment: I have seen that as well, and tried it. It does not work for me, but not that this is **not** a Chrome specific issue, but a systemwide issue on my machine.

Comment: Then I would try uninstalling the offending fonts, and subsequently reinstalling. A guide to how to manage this can be found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1076-fonts-delete.html).

Comment: Remove the font *and* clear the font cache by  this file: 'C:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT'. After that, reinstall the font.

Comment: I tried the disable direct write that Kristian suggested and it worked for me